# How to return "theme" as a response to ajax?

Tags: drupal, jquery

I am having a php function call in one of my template files in drupal.

If i return this template via theme hook as a ajax response the function is not executing,

But if i call this template directly via theme hook, the function is executing!

Can anyone please help me in returning a "theme" as ajax response?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions `c#` when clearly there's nothing related to `c#` in your question.

Comment: Sorry, that was by mistake! edited it now...

Comment: that should work, try calling from some other file

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that two jquery function make an error.

Did you check the firebug console?